Oracle: how to add a decimal point to an integer
Oracle 19c.
I am reading a file and need to store the following values into a NUMBER column:
000036720
000008425
000754070
000086640
000001645

Desired output will be:
367.20
84.25
7540.70
866.40
16.45

I can use SUBSTR(), but was wondering if there is a better/easier approach. I played with TO_CHAR(), but can't seem to find a mask I need.

Hint : NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS

simple: '000754070'/100. Oracle will automatically cast it to a number and then apply the division which will move the right-most two digits to the right of the decimal point. If you want the trailing 0 to actually show up in your client then you're back to a string again: LTRIM(TO_CHAR('000754070'/100,'9999999.00'))
